Cannot Enable Livepatch on 24.04.1
After running pro enable livepatch, I recieve the error below:
Unable to install Livepatch client: Failed running command '/usr/bin/snap install canonical-livepatch' [exit(1)]. Message: error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run hook connect-plug-etc-update-motd-d of snap "canonical-livepatch" (run hook "connect-plug-etc-update-motd-d": 
-----
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/local/share/doc /usr/local/share/doc none bind,ro 0 0): cannot open directory "/usr/local": permission denied
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/gimp/2.0/help /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help none bind,ro 0 0): cannot write to "/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/gimp/2.0/help" because it would affect the host in "/var/lib/snapd"
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/javascript/jquery /usr/share/javascript/jquery none bind,ro 0 0): cannot write to "/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/javascript/jquery" because it would affect the host in "/var/lib/snapd"
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/javascript/sphinxdoc /usr/share/javascript/sphinxdoc none bind,ro 0 0): cannot write to "/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/javascript/sphinxdoc" because it would affect the host in "/var/lib/snapd"
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/libreoffice/help /usr/share/libreoffice/help none bind,ro 0 0): cannot write to "/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/libreoffice/help" because it would affect the host in "/var/lib/snapd"
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/sphinx_rtd_theme /usr/share/sphinx_rtd_theme none bind,ro 0 0): cannot write to "/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/sphinx_rtd_theme" because it would affect the host in "/var/lib/snapd"
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/xubuntu-docs /usr/share/xubuntu-docs none bind,ro 0 0): cannot write to "/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/xubuntu-docs" because it would affect the host in "/var/lib/snapd"
cp: cannot remove '/etc/update-motd.d/99-livepatch-kernel-upgrade-required': Permission denied

SERVICE          ENTITLED  STATUS       DESCRIPTION
anbox-cloud      yes       disabled     Scalable Android in the cloud
esm-apps         yes       enabled      Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications
esm-infra        yes       enabled      Expanded Security Maintenance for Infrastructure
landscape        yes       disabled     Management and administration tool for Ubuntu
livepatch        yes       disabled     Canonical Livepatch service
realtime-kernel* yes       disabled     Ubuntu kernel with PREEMPT_RT patches integrated

Please assist.  Thank you.

Hello I had a similar issue.  I was finally able to reinstall and run Livepatch on ubuntu 24.04 snap after following these instructions: https://github.com/snap-stanford/snap/issues/240 and then sudo pro enable livepatch.  Hope this helps.
